# Excel - Index and match many to many results vertically

Tags: arrays, excel, vlookup

in excel document, I have in sheet "Documents" reference nr. with corresponding values, for example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Reference | Document |
| 12345 | Document1 |
| 12345 | Document2 |
| 12345 | Document3 |
| 54321 | Contract1 |
| 54321 | Contract2 |

In sheet "Main", I have the following

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Reference |  | Document |
| 12345 |  |  |
| 12345 |  |  |
| 12345 |  |  |
| 12345 |  |  |
| 12345 |  |  |
| 12345 |  |  |
| 12345 |  |  |
| 12345 |  |  |
| 12345 |  |  |

I would need result from sheet "Documents" from column B in column C of sheet "Main". In sheet "Main" there are always 9 reference numbers (for each) reference) but in sheet "Documents" reference nr. varies from 2 to 8. So, for these reference nr.in sheet "Main" which are excessive, I would need some kind of different result, for example #N/A or similar...

I have tried with array formulas with no success.

Help would be appricated...

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to-

```
=MAP(A2:A10,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(Documents!B:B,Documents!A:A=x),ROW(x)-ROW($A$1)),"Your Message")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, it doesn't work for me. Maybe the file is too big, excel just freezes...

Comment: Then instead referencing full column, specify fixed range like `Documents!B2:B50000`.